# Asking help if this is indeed a Haro elevated chainstay mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike, vintage

Dad bought this as a new old stock from a bike shop here in the Philippines.

It had Suntour derailleurs but generic shifters. The front derailleur spring broke whatever shifter it had. I doubt that it is a Haro because the long tube, between the seat tube and headset is straight and not the usual curved Haro.

[image]
[image]
[image]